# how to just input new line in insert mode with omnicompletion?

Tags: vim, vi, omnicomplete

using omnicompletion(?), how can I just input new line in insert mode, not visiting next suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is documented at `:help popupmenu-keys`:

> ```
> CTRL-E          End completion, go back to what was there before selecting a
>                 match (what was typed or longest common string).
> ```

Depending on your `'completeopt'` option, there may be alternatives, e.g. pressing `<C-N>` / `<C-P>` until nothing is selected.

You can also map another key for this, e.g. `<Esc>`:

```
imap <expr> <Esc> pumvisible() ? '<C-e>' : '<Esc>'
```

Comment: I have not tested enough but I think it can work: `inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? '<C-e>' : '<CR>'`